# Lost Service reward

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I completed one of the special Service to the Empire tasks, but the game immediately crashed and I never got the reward of the droids.  Is there some way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the cargo hold, even though it's not lit up. The droid reward boxes should be there, at least that's what happened for me.

Comment: I presumed he had done so already, but hopefully this winds up being the correct answer!

Comment: I did try that, and the reward was not there.  It has moved me on to the Bucs reward, which I am about to complete.  I am hoping that when I finish it, the droids may pop up too.  I also tried setting by the clock, but that didn't work.  I have an S3 and the game has been crashing constantly since the update.  When it does, I get weird combinations of what is saved or not.  It will keep the bitizen I put on a level before the crash, but not the level I stocked right before that, so I will have to stock the same item on the level again.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is check to see if your online version of the game has the reward or at least the stuff you've built so you can claim it.

It's not quite clear how you force it to load, but in my experience it seems to come up with this option when I close the game and re-open it.

Failing this back-up, I believe that you may have to redo the tasks from whatever point your game seems to have reset itself.

Answer (score -1):

The rewards are recruiting officer > bux > droids > imperial marches level.  If you are on the "next task" and it is bux, then you got a recruiting officer, not droids.